# Jasmin HelloWorld Example Failing

Tags: java, jasmin

I'm having a problem executing a newly compiled HelloWorld.j from the jasmin-2.4 distribution.

I downloaded jasmin-2.4. I can compile ok using:

java -jar jasmin.jar examples\HelloWorld.j

the output is:

Generated: NoJad\j.class

When I execute the newly compiled program:

java NoJad.j

an exception is thrown:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: NoJad/j, method: main
signature: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V) Expecting to find object/array on stack
Could not find the main class: NoJad.j.  Program will exit.

I'm inclined to believe that this is a bug in the HelloWorld.j example. Perhaps a new verifier has caught a bug???

Note 1: the pre-compiled HelloWorld.class in the distribution works as expected.

Note 2: I'm using this version of java
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)

Here's the HelloWorld.j file from the distribution:

```
; --- Copyright Jonathan Meyer 1996. All rights reserved. -----------------
; File:      jasmin/examples/HelloWorld.j
; Author:    Jonathan Meyer, 10 July 1996
; Purpose:   Prints out "Hello World!"
; -------------------------------------------------------------------------


.class public NoJad.j
.super java/lang/Object

;
; standard initializer
.method public <init>()V
   aload_0

   invokenonvirtual java/lang/Object/<init>()V
   return
.end method

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   .limit stack 2
   .limit locals 2

   bipush 2
   astore 0
   bipush 3
   astore 1

   aload 0
   aload 1
   astore 0
   astore 1

   return
.end method
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the HelloWorld.j file is bogus. See this thread: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasmin/forums/forum/349052/topic/3330588